# PowerShell: To combine text files into a csv file

Tags: powershell

=== Problem Statement ===

Combine all the text file into a csv file. This csv files should have three fields. Index, Filename and File Content.

Once done will this file be viewable in excel properly or should I handle certain cases ?

=== Pseudo logic ===

1. Input: Define how the script receives input (command-line arguments, user input, or configuration file).

   - Include the folder path where the files are located.
   - Optionally, specify the desired output file name.
2. Retrieve Files: Implement a method to fetch all the files present in the specified folder.
3. Process Files: For each file found in the folder, perform the following actions:
   a. Read Content: Open the file and read its content.
   b. Count Lines: Count the number of lines in the file.
4. Create Data Structure: Define a suitable data structure (e.g., array, list, dictionary, struct) to hold file details (name, content, line count).
5. Output Generation: After processing all files, create the output file in CSV-like format.

   - Organize the gathered information (file name, content, line count) into rows.
   - Format the content, enclosing it within double quotes and handling any existing double quotes.
   - Format the rows as comma-separated values to represent each file's details.
6. Save Output: Save the CSV-formatted data into the output file.
7. Completion Message: Display a message indicating that the output file has been generated, along with the file name used.
8. End of the Script.

=== PowerShell Script ===

```
# Function to get file content and line count
function Get-FileDetails ($filePath) {
    # Read the content of the file and store it in $content
    $content = Get-Content $filePath -Raw

    # Count the number of lines in the file and store it in $lineCount
    $lineCount = (Get-Content $filePath).Count

    # Create a hashtable with file details and return it
    return @{
        FileName = $filePath
        Content = $content
        LineCount = $lineCount
    }
}

# Main script
if ($args.Count -lt 1) {
    Write-Host "Usage: .\file_details_script.ps1 <FolderPath> [<OutputFile>]"
    Exit
}

# Get the folder path from the first argument
$FolderPath = $args[0]

# Use the default output file name if not provided as the second argument
$OutputFile = "output.csv"
if ($args.Count -gt 1) {
    $OutputFile = $args[1]
}

# Get all files in the specified folder and store them in $files
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -File

# Initialize an empty array to store the file details
$outputData = @()

# Process each file and gather details
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $fileDetails = Get-FileDetails -filePath $file.FullName
    $outputData += $fileDetails
}

# Generate output CSV file
foreach ($line in $outputData) {
    $index = [array]::IndexOf($outputData, $line) + 1
    $formattedContent = '"' + $line.Content.Replace('"', '""') + '"'
    $outputLine = "$index, $($line.FileName), $formattedContent, $($line.LineCount)"
    $outputLine | Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -Append
}

Write-Host "Output file generated: $OutputFile"
```

=== Usage ===

.\file_details_script.ps1 "C:\Example\Folder" "results.csv"

Comment: Alright, so what's the problem? What happens when you run the script?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a CSV manually, you can just use `ConvertTo-Csv` or `Export-Csv` and let PowerShell do the work. It accepts an object.

Also you don't need to read the content twice, you can use `Out-String` to convert it to a raw string instead.

Here's a very simplified example (note that I used `$PSScriptRoot`, you can of course pass it in as a parameter instead):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot -File | ForEach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName
    [pscustomobject] @{
        'FileName' = $_.Name;
        'LineCount' = $content | Measure-Object -Line | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Lines
        'Content' = $content | Out-String;
    }
} | ConvertTo-Csv # or Use Export-Csv -Path xyz to write a file directly.
```

Comment: Cool thanks, this looks like a better way

Comment: Good advice, but note that `Out-String` - regrettably - appends a trailing newline to the content: see [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444). You can avoid its use by using `Get-Content -Raw` instead (`Measure-Object -Line` also counts lines in _multiline_ strings and ignores a trailing newline). This will also speed up the command noticeably.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of that! PowerShell is always good for surprises :)